# Printing a table of values 1 through x (number of months)

Tags: python

I'm trying to print out a table of values regarding rabbits multiplying, the rest of the table I've got figured out but for some reason I cannot come up with a way to print out the number of months that have passed in the first column, 1, 2, 3, etc. It seems so simple in my head but I can't figure out how to make it happen.

I have this right now:

```
    for n in range(number):
        i = 0
        print(months[i + 1]
```

This may seem like a dumb question but I'm new to python and coding in general so any help is much appreciated.

edit: sorry not very clear, i want my output to look something like this:

```
    Months  Adults  Babies  Total
    1       x       x       x
    2
    3
    4
```

x's are just examples, i already figured out how to calculate those columns, i just don't know how to get the months column.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you want.  Perhaps you could edit the question to show a sample of your desired output.

Comment: Please add expected output to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
for n in range(0, number):
    print(months[n])
```